# Programmactially adding picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Ok so I am testing with adding a picturebox to my winform app.  I am finally asking here, because when ever I look up how to do this I don't see anything different than what I am doing.  Here is the code:

```
namespace AddPanel
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\xoswaldr\Desktop\OrangeLogo.jpg";
        pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 40);
        pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);

    }
}
}
```

That is the entire code, because I am just trying to test adding a picturebox for something else I'm working on.  What I am trying to do with this is when I run the program it puts the picturebox in the form, but that doesn't happen.  The form is just blank.

-----EDIT------------

Here is the Form1.Designer.cs code

```
namespace AddPanel
{
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(690, 381);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

}
}
```

and here is the Program.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AddPanel
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
}
```

Is there something in the designer that is blocking it or something that I haven't added?

Comment: Is your program able to access that location?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Even if I pick a file that doesn't exist, I still see a black picture box (with a small white box and a red x). Not sure why it isn't working for the OP.

Comment: The posted code is not the problem - works fine for me as is.

Comment: Any chance form1 is not your startup object and you have another form? What's in your Programs.cs file? Or perhaps you have another control blocking the picture box that is in only visible in designer mode (Form1.Designer.cs would show adding the control).

Comment: Hmmm your edit looks fine. The OrangeLogo.jpg file doesn't happen to have the same colour background as the form does it? If it does and the image is too big to fit the picture box, perhaps it looks like there is no picture box because you are only seeing the background of the top left corner of the image file. What if you set this the code as well? `pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;`

Comment: Add `pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom` and have a try.

Answer (score 2):

Since your code looks correct, is it possible there is another control covering the picture box?

Try bringing it to the Front:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox1 = new PictureBox
    {
        BackColor = Color.Black,
        ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\xoswaldr\Desktop\OrangeLogo.jpg",
        Location = new Point(20, 40),
        Name = "pictureBox1",
        Size = new Size(100, 50)
    };

    this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);

    pictureBox1.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: If the OP is trying to add the PictureBox to a Panel or some other sort of container, that could be part of their problem as well, since it looks like the main form is the parent in this case.

Comment: It wasn't in the code I posted because I took it out, but I had seen this when trying to figure out what was wrong and tried it. It didn't work.  I'm wondering if the problem is my work computer, but I have run other projects with no problems on this computer before.

Comment: For some reason it works if I put the code in a function and then call the function.  If I put it in the Form1_Load function it doesn't work.

Comment: Add `SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom` and have try.

Answer (score 0):

The picture may not be completely displayed, just set the SizeMode to have a try:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
```